# Sync MySQL contacts with mail server or Outlook/Mac Mail

Tags: mysql, contacts, synchronization

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Setup:

Database - MySql 5.5.9 on Mac Mini OSX office server

Mail Server - Kerio Connect

Applications - Outlook, Mac Mail, Contacts, etc. on a variety of PC's, Macs, iPhones, etc.

My company has an internal Mac Mini server for our MySQL database that is not used for any email services. I need to sync or push our list of contacts from the database to either a public folder on Kerio Connect, or to an email program. Kerio automatically syncs between devices and computers, so if I can get the records from the database to one program like Outlook the rest will be taken care of.

I've tried out the demo version of GeniusConnect, but have encountered numerous bugs. Is this the only option for an out-of-box solution?